# Find if a list contains several values - SQL Server Xquery

Tags: sql-server, xquery-sql

I am storing a XML data into a table called `BikeTable`. The XML data is coming from an object that is being serialized using .Net serializer.
BikeTable would look like this :

```
Id - UniqueIdentifier
XmlData - XML
```

The XML stored in the `XmlData` column looks like this :

Record 1 :

```
<Bike>
    <Material>
        <Cage>EIECH</Cage>
        <Mpn>B258-C436-B001</
    </Material>
    <Roles>
        <string>Race</string>
        <string>Mountain</string>
        <string>City</string>
    </Roles>
</Bike>
```

Record 2 :

```
<Bike>
    <Material>
        <Cage>ABCDE</Cage>
        <Mpn>B258-C436-B001</Mpn>
    </Material>
    <Roles>
        <string>Race</string>
    </Roles>
</Bike>
```

I want to be able to find the records in my table that will contain for example Race and Mountain.

Example if I want the Ids of the record that contains 'Road'and 'Mountain" the only way I found is like this :

```
select Id 
from BikeTable
where XmlData.exist('/Bike/Roles/string[contains(., "Road")]') = 1 
   or XmlData.exist('/Bike/Roles/string[contains(., "Mountain")]') = 1
```

I don't like this option because it forces me to generate the query if I want to find records that would match one or several roles. 
Roles can contains unlimited number of values and I need to be able to find the records that will one or more values. 
Ex : records containing Race, records containing Race or Montain, records containing City, records containing City and Mountain etc.

Is there any way to know if a list contains several values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. This is a bit of a guess though, as you say you want to do a `SELECT *`; something that is impossible to provide any data for without the DDL of the table. Thus, instead, I've returned the Cage and Mpn of the Bike:

```
CREATE TABLE BikeTable (xmlData xml);

--The Close tag for Mpn was missing in your sample data, I assume it wasn't mean to be
INSERT INTO BikeTable
VALUES('<Bike>
    <Material>
        <Cage>EIECH</Cage>
        <Mpn>B258-C436-B001</Mpn>
    </Material>
    <Roles>
        <string>Race</string>
        <string>Mountain</string>
        <string>City</string>
    </Roles>
</Bike>')
GO
WITH Bikes AS (
    SELECT B.Material.value('(Cage/text())[1]','varchar(15)') AS Cage, --Data Type guessed
           B.Material.value('(Mpn/text())[1]','varchar(15)') AS Mpn, --Data Type guessed
           BR.String.value('(./text())[1]','varchar(15)') AS String --Data Type guessed
    FROM BikeTable BT
         CROSS APPLY BT.xmlData.nodes('/Bike/Material') B(Material)
         CROSS APPLY BT.xmlData.nodes('/Bike/Roles/string') BR(String))
SELECT Cage, Mpn
FROM Bikes
GROUP BY Cage, Mpn
HAVING COUNT(String) > 1;

GO

DROP TABLE BikeTable;
```

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer. I think I did not explain my problem very well, or I did not understand your query. I don't see how I can find a record containing a specific value like 'Mountain' or 'Mountain OR Road'

Comment: Your question was *"Is there any way to know if a list contains several values?"*, which is what that query does: It returns values that have multiple values for `string`. This is why expected results are really important. Perhaps you need to now use a `WHERE` and `IN`, and get rid of the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`. Update your question with more detail, and let me know, and I'll be happy to look; but I can't make more guesses than I already have. :)

Comment: Yes sorry about that, my question was not clear enough. I updated it with more details.  And using your request and your comment I was able to have a first result. One thing I wondering now is the performance.

Comment: @Guigui Provided you're making use of `text()`, then the x-query should perform pretty well. If you don't use `text()`, then that actually adds extra overhead to the query (I can't recall the specific reason, apologies).